# Hibernate exceptions keep getting handled by RuntimeException.class rather than HibernateException.class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a ControllerAdvice set up, with two exception handlers; one for any Hibernate exception (HibernateException.class) and one for any other Runtime exception (RuntimeException.class)

```
@ExceptionHandler(HibernateException.class)
public String handleHibernateException(HibernateException exc, Model theModel) {

    String message = "An error has occured: " + exc.getLocalizedMessage() + "\r\n";

    myLogger.warning(message);

    theModel.addAttribute("exception", message);

    return "testing";
}


@ExceptionHandler(RuntimeException.class)
public String handleRuntimeExceptions(RuntimeException exc, Model theModel) {

    if (exc instanceof HibernateException) {

        return handleHibernateException((HibernateException) exc.getCause(), theModel);
    }   

    String message = "An error has occured: " + exc.getLocalizedMessage() + "\n"
            + exc.getCause().getCause().toString() + "\r\n";
    myLogger.warning(message);

    theModel.addAttribute("exception", message);

    return "testing";
```

I'm testing this out by messing up my query statements, which gives me a QuerySyntaxException; a subclass of HibernateException. And yet, it is still handled by my Runtime exception method.

Comment: how about if you comment out `handleRuntimeExceptions` method?

Comment: If I comment it out, it still does not work.. even if I change the exception to QuerySyntaxException. hmm..

Answer (score 0):

I think @ExceptionHandler exactly matched the Exact Exception name that is QuerySyntaxException.Could you try putting QuerySyntaxException.